# Encrypted Column as a part of Primary Key, Group by not working, Sorting, Search Overhead

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting, encryption, grouping

I am having a primary key column in a table, which was designed as an unencrypted column in earlier stage. Now we are planning to make this as an encrypted column by using the SQL servers Inbuilt granular encryption.
I use the following sample code for testing.

I am having the following requirements on the same column.

1. The column is used very extensively as a foreign key in many other tables.
2. In the application same column is Indexed in multiple tables as a part of composite primary key/ Non clustered Indexes .
3. Need to search the column based on wild card search
4. Sort the column in both directions

The problem which I am facing is whenver I am encrypting the value it is getting different values each time.

1. I am not able to do a group by on the same column
2. when need to perform wild card based search or sorting it needed to unencrypt all data stored in the column.

Is there any better way to tackle these issues? I dont prefer using any user defined function for the same.

Please help me out.

```
CREATE DATABASE Bank
GO
USE Bank
GO

 CREATE TABLE Account ( 
  AccountId int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
  AccountNumber varchar(50),  
  EncryptedAccountNumber varbinary(128)  )
GO


  -----------------
   CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY  PASSWORD = 'Pa$$w0rd'

    -----------------
    CREATE CERTIFICATE BankCert
      WITH SUBJECT = 'Account Numbers';
GO
    -----------------    
    CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY BankAccountKey  
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256  
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE BankCert;
GO

 --Encryption-----------------
      OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY BankAccountKey  
      DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE BankCert;   --insert original and encrypted values 

INSERT INTO Account
    VALUES ('123456789', ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('BankAccountKey'), '123456789')),
    ('987654321', ENCRYPTBYKEY(KEY_GUID('BankAccountKey'), '987654321'))

SELECT * FROM Account

--Decryption-----------------------------------------------------------
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY BankAccountKey
      DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE BankCert;
GO

--list original and decrypted values
SELECT
    AccountNumber,
    EncryptedAccountNumber,
    LEN(EncryptedAccountNumber) AS Size,
    CONVERT(varchar, DECRYPTBYKEY(EncryptedAccountNumber)) AS DecryptedAccountNumber
FROM Account
```

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use the account number as a foreign key?

Comment: Account no is not the real column. I explained the scenario using this sample.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use that column as a foreign key?

Comment: Thanks. Your solution will work. But It's an existing system. If avoiding that column as a foreign key, we need to use another unencrypted column for mapping in other tables. This needs tremendous changes within stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

All column level encryption inside of the databases is non-deterministic and random. You could use SQL Server 2016 Always Encrypted and configure it for deterministic encryption, but with low cardinality you would be running the risk of someone using the driver to create a hash table of your account numbers and defeat the encryption. It would be best to remove it from the primary key and remove the column on all tables it references as a foreign key, that way it would only be on one table and encrypted. As far as searching, you could create a hash on the last four digits to narrow the results before decrypting. That would reduce the workload.